# Second Animation is not working after Collision?

Tags: unity, c#, unityscript

I want to show an accident of Character with car. so I wrote this code
and in update function I wrote this...

```
        if (Once) {

                    Criminal.GetComponent<Animation> ().Play ("Running"); // after collision This animation will work
                    Criminal.GetComponent<BezierMover> ().enabled = true;
                    TrafficCar.GetComponent<BezierMover> ().enabled = true;
        }
void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Vehicle") {
        if (!Criminal.GetComponent<Animation> ().IsPlaying ("Stumbling"))
            Criminal.GetComponent<Animation> ().Play ("Stumbling"); // Animation for Accident
        Criminal.GetComponent<BezierMover> ().enabled = false; // to Deactivate the AI Script.
        TrafficCar.GetComponent<BezierMover> ().enabled = false; //to Deactivate the Trrafic cars Path Script.
        Once = true; 
    }
}
```

but after first animation second animation should work but this is not happening..

Comment: Which Animation is supposed to be the *second animation*?. And, is your if condition inside *Update* function?

Comment: @AdityaYadav Animation in if condition is second animation and yes it is inside update function...

Comment: Did you try switching the 2 animations to check if "Running" animations works well? Did you try commenting the `Criminal.GetComponent<Animation> ().Play ("Stumbling");` line to check if it is not due to launching animation when previous animation still running? Did you try putting a breakpoint in the `update` function to check if `Once` is still set to true?